# Define a Connection String on Web Host similar to EF Connection String in Debug Mode on Local Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-hosting, web.config-transform

This s the connection String I am using in my local asp.net mvc site, I want to publish the website over a web hosting. They have SQL Instance of `.\SQLEXPRESS12` and I have created a database name `myapp_db` as well. I have created a user with that db also. How can I modify the EF generated Connection String, and will it effect my auto generated models too ?

P.S. I know this question might not be StackOverflow's guidelines, but I would appreciate any help.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DCHSurgical_DBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Areas.ADMIN.Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Areas.ADMIN.Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Areas.ADMIN.Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myapp_db;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this part of your `connectionString` like this:

```
< ... data source=Server's IP Address,Port;initial catalog=myapp_db;
      user id=username that you have created;password=yourpassword;
       MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
       ... />
```

Comment: It did work , but I am getting error that `myapp_db` cannot be opened by user `myusername`. However if I go in ASP.NET enterprise manager and enter the same credentials it works