# how to solve this error "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there anything wrong web.config page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="5"/>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

  </system.web>

  <appSettings>

    <add key="dsn" value="Data Source=184.14.14.239;Initial Catalog=Testing;User ID=sa;Password=June28241234"/>
    <add key="ReportServer" value="http://184.14.14.239/ReportServer/"/>
    <add key="SSRSViewerPath" value="Pages/ReportViewer.aspx"/>
    <add key="ReportLocation" value="ArvindLapserReports/"/>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="200000000"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

In PC its working fine but server getting this below error.

[image]

could you please help me. how to resolve this problem.

Comment: You must change your connectionString so that it has the ip and port address of your server. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33145684/2946329

Comment: also occurs when web config generated by visual studio could not be parsed by IIS.

Comment: Hi Akbari thanks for your response. this connection string is working. if i remove this line "<httpRuntime executionTimeout="5"/>" this code is code is working

Comment: Hi Akbari with out this "<httpRuntime executionTimeout="5"/>" if i execute my code it was working but after few minutes we are getting error like "System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out." thats why i added this code

Comment: The `httpRuntime` seems declared twice in `system.web` element, try combine them to just one element: `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="5" targetFramework="4.5" />`.

Comment: Hi @Tetsuya Yamamoto thank you so much now its working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected on your sample, you have two `httpRuntime` elements in `system.web` element, and you should change it to a single element like this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="5" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

**NB:** The configuration file convention allows only single child element with certain name for every parent elements.